# XML Button background color not changing

Tags: xml, android-studio

I have this XML tag:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@color/colorTheme"
        style="@style/ButtonStyle"
        android:text="Next"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewFooterGetStarted"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.968" />
```

For some reason the background color of my button doesn't change. I've tried using only style.xml:

```
<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_get_started</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTheme</item>
    </style>
```

And still has the default purple color. `android:background` doesn't have any effect either.
What could be causing the background color not to change?

Edit: I found the solution. Turns out `android:background` changes the color but only if `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>` tag is used instead of `<button>` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with AppCompatButtom instead of Button

Replace your Button With AppCompatButtom

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="305dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:background="@color/colorTheme"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:text="Next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageViewFooterGetStarted"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.968" />
```

Hope its work !!

Answer (score 0):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhoEx.png)
Replace <Button... /> with <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton... /> in code of Activity_main.xml